# Facebook like box dark color scheme not working in my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have just added new Facebook like box for my website but unfortunately the dark color scheme not function properly.

Attached is the iframe code:

```
<iframe style="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; WIDTH: 250px; HEIGHT: 520px; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fifocussolutions.com.my&amp;width=250&amp;height=520&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp; " frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

It will not allow me to add in allowTransparency code inside the iframe.
Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The facebook "lightbox" effect isn't accomplished with iframes. It's done using absolute positioned divs. There are a number of javaScript libraries out there that make it very easy to create a facebook-like lightbox. Google for facebook lightbox and select one you like.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. however, i am using Google Business Sitebuilder to build my website and unfortunately it only allow IFRAME plugin to be used and not allow to use any other plugin.. any other ways to solve this problem? appreciate much for the help, thanks @Steve Atkinson